# What to do if an answer reframes the problem

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

What should I do if I ask a question and the answer recommends that I change my problem so that the answer works?

### What I Tried

I went ahead and edited the question to reflect a few times that the answer does not fit the question because it modifies my problem. I left a few comments pointing these things out, but the answer was still upvoted.

---

I have seen a few cases of this. For example a person will ask how to use *A* to send data but someone will say "you should use *B* instead". Granted sometimes *A* is still a feasible approach, but perhaps not the best.

Here is a case that happened to me directly, but I have seen better examples with other individuals: [How to make an unique id for an object that is not random](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54393003/how-to-make-an-unique-id-for-an-object-that-is-not-random)

---

What should a poster do?

Comment: Simple... don't accept the answer.

Comment: It might also be valuable to consider the possibility that your question isn't clear.

Comment: @KevinB Thanks for your reply and taking the time to read. I made a few edits to clarify as much of the question and to explain that the answer was changing my problem to answer the question. I do agree my question is not the best, though.

Comment: The problem with the qustion you pointed out is that the question that you asked initially, is the one that was answered. You then changed the requirements of the question to match what your actual requirements were. That isn't the answerer's fault, and they are not in any way obligated to modify their answer to fit the needs of your updated question. If anything, you did them a dis-service by changing your question after an answer had been provided. That answer is a perfectly valid answer for the question you initially asked. Changing the question after it has been answered is frowned upon.

Comment: The question as it stands is still quite a bit unclear, for reasons presented in the comments.

Comment: The answerer didn't tell you to change the question into a question they were answering, they responded to your statement that the answer didn't cover a problem you hadn't included in the question by telling you to include, in the question, the information you had previously left out, that constrains answers to it.

Comment: If you look at the timeline of that question he posted an answer that would work and 15 minutes later you updated the question to add more information that made it not work with the provided answer.

Comment: @JoeW I disagree. I only added the details because it was not clear to the poster. However, needing `ID`s for a non distributed system is fairly trivial and adding that detail, I felt, was unnecessary. That being said, I am asking about the bigger picture not necessarily my concrete example. I even mentioned it was not a great example.

Comment: Not counting the "debug my code" and "can you google this for me" questions, ~95% of all questions are from programmers that are trying to solve the wrong problem.  Self-inflicted by starting off the wrong way.  So reformulating the problem is essential to get them ahead.

Comment: What Servy said. Ironically this meta question is misframed because what you claim happened, didn't happen!

Comment: @J_Strauton, clearly the upvoted answer in the example case didn't tell you what you really wanted to know, but it was a perfectly good answer to the original question you actually posed.  Just look at this comments thread and observe the meta effect on the question and its answers to get an idea of the community's opinion on that.  Having asked the wrong question and gotten a good and good-faith answer to it, the polite thing to do would be to accept the answer.  Of course, you have no obligation to do so, but please, at least don't modify the question out from under the answer.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

> What should a poster do?

Nothing. Alternative solutions to problems are *still* solutions. In fact, sometimes, they are the *best* solutions. Lots of seemingly intractable problems are actually [X-Y problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), where the best or only solution will come from approaching the problem in an entirely different way.

They may not work for you personally, and that's fine. If it isn't the best answer for you, then you don't have to upvote it, and you shouldn't accept it.

But there's no reason to remove the answer, because it might still be useful for someone else having the same problem but with fewer restrictions/constraints in solving it. The mission of Stack Overflow is two-fold: we are not only here to help the person who originally asked the question, but also to help a legion of Googlers with the same question.

Editing the question to clarify why that approach (or other approaches like it) won't work for you is, of course, a good idea. Good for you. This will help clarify to others that you're still looking for a different solution (as will the fact that you haven't accepted an answer).

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: Yes, it does. Thanks for that answer.

Answer (score 0):

People often ask "How to solve my problem with doing Y", when they'd be better off just doing X in the first place because they just don't know any better or didn't consider it. If you have considered the "better" option and either can't use it for any kind of reason, or even if you are going with X in the end but are still curious if/how Y *could* be done, then mention that in your question.

People will 1. see that you already know that doing X is the better option, so there's no reason to point that out to you and 2. see that there's an actual reason why you *have* to do Y and "do X instead" just doesn't fix your problem.

If people still disregard your original question, downvote their answer, leave a commend pointing out that they gave the right answer to the wrong question, in case they just misread it (that happens too!).

But always keep in mind that answers on Stack Overflow aren't just for the person asking the question; even if a particular answer doesn't fix your problem, if you think it may still help someone else with a similar problem, then there's some value in that as well, and you shouldn't downvote it.

Comment: this wasn't an X/Y, it was simply unclear. The OP didn't specify whether or not it was a distributed system until after it was answered.